# Xcode 10 Could not find any available simulators for iOS when install Carthage dependencies

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, carthage

I'm trying to install Carthage dependencies in my Xcode project with the

```
Carthage bootstrap --platform iOS
```

command line but It's fail and I have this message in my terminal:

```
Could not find any available simulators for iOS
```

I've just updated Xcode with the 10 version then the simulators are already installed.

I've also tried to delete each one and reinstall only one with iOS 12.

I have still the same error.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to you or not, but, this "seems" to be an issue with 10.1 ... and yes, once you have it installed, there's nothing you seem to be able to do to fix it ☹️ See [this issue](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2602) for more details

Comment: I installed Xcode10.0 through App Store, but the issue remains the same.

Comment: I'm getting this, too, on Xcode 9.4.1 with Carthage v 0.31.0.  Xcode-select does show Xcode 9's build tools selected.  Any Carthage command which invokes a build shows this for me, not just `bootstrap.`

Comment: I've been having this issue, an upgrade to v0.31.1 solved it.

Comment: Issue happens for me with latest Carthage (0.34)

Answer (score 26):

What worked for me was uninstalling Carthage and installing it again.

```
brew uninstall carthage --force
brew install carthage
```

Comment: Just upgrade carthage.  `brew upgrade carthage`

Comment: @AlexZavatone That works if there is a new version. Otherwise, you need to do the trick I mention.

Comment: Tomas, the reason that this happened was because there *was* a new version that changed the format of the data.

Comment: Alex, then you probably faced a different issue, because upgrade didn't work.

Comment: Interesting.  It's actually the exact issue that I faced.  Hmmm.  I wonder what didn't work,  Tomáš.  So much to keep track of under the hood.  Now, if an install *did* work we would have expected an up*grade* (not update) to also work as it should have installed the same thing.  Argh.  Do you remember the version that was installed when you did reinstall it?

Comment: The problem was I had the latest version, so upgrade did nothing. There was no new version to be installed. I don't remember the version anymore, but I think it was v0.31.1?

Comment: I dont usually like that kind of sultions... But worked for me ^^'

Answer (score 15):

Upgrading to v0.31.1 or v0.31.2 fixes it:

```
brew update && brew upgrade carthage
```

Answer (score 3):

When a new xcode version comes out, it tends to happen. You can try to update Carthage with `brew upgrade carthage` if installed with Brew

Answer (score 3):

After installing Xcode 10.1, I had trouble even with Carthage 0.31.2. But I also have a habit of deleting all simulators when installing Xcode major versions. Adding a simulator for iOS 12.1 fixed things.

Comment: Just upgrade carthage.  `brew upgrade carthage`

Answer (score 3):

Just upgrade your Carthage.

As indicated in other answers the cause behind this is that a key indicating simulator model availability changed in a recent update to Xcode 10.x.  It was

```
"availability" : "(available)",
```

and it is now

```
"isAvailable" : true,
```

Upgrading Carthage to 0.33.0 fixes this.

Using brew, enter the following to update Carthage

```
brew upgrade carthage
```

Notice the word is up**grade**, not update.

Check the version of carthage

```
brew list --versions carthage
```

`carthage 0.33.0`

And in the terminal at the root of your project, enter this to rebuild your Carthage dependancies.

```
carthage bootstrap --platform iOS
```

They all should build as expected.

You can check the data format of the available simulators through this command.

`xcrun simctl list devices --json`

Answer (score 2):

try to run

> sudo brew install --HEAD carthage

Since Xcode 10.1 beta, Structures of xcrun simctl list devices --json is changed.

Before

```
{
  "devices" : {
    "iOS 12.0" : [
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "name" : "iPhone 5s",
        "udid" : "A52BF797-F6F8-47F1-B559-68B66B553B23"
      }
  ]
}
```

After

```
{
  "devices" : {
    "iOS 12.0" : [
      {
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : "YES",
        "name" : "iPhone 5s",
        "udid" : "A52BF797-F6F8-47F1-B559-68B66B553B23"
      }
  ]
}
```

Because of this changes, parsing on Xcode 10.1 is failed.

Answer (score 0):

*Uninstalling and installing Carthage trick worked for me!*

```
brew uninstall carthage —force
```

[image: Screenshot]

```
brew install carthage
```

Comment: Just upgrade carthage.  `brew upgrade carthage`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was solved.

1. Close xcode
2. `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/`
3. Open xcode
4. Create new project
5. Run empty project on any simulator
6. execute `carthage update`

Comment: Except, Xcode does not automatically install any simulators and you're left with a broken sim install after following your steps.